# node-soap: It not found the distribution method

Tags: node.js, soap, soapui, soap-client, node-soap

Try using the node soap call a web service does not work, but if it works in SoapUI

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://190.129.208.178:96/PasarelaServices/CustomerServices?wsdl';
var args = { "key": '12345', "parametros": 'parameters...' };
soap.createClient(url, function (err, client) {
  console.log(client.describe());
  console.log(client.describe().CustomerServices.CustomerServicesPort.solicitarPago);
  client.CustomerServices.CustomerServicesPort.solicitarPago(args, function (err, result, raw, soapHeader) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result)
    console.log(raw);
  });
});
```

in SoapUI request would:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.vlink.com.bo/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:solicitarPago>
         <key>12345</key>
         <parametros>parameters...</parametros>
      </ser:solicitarPago>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please check the raw request in soapui and see if any of the headers being missed in `node-soap` call?

Comment: I suspect it may be the prefix function <ser:solicitarPago>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can solve it with:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = 'http://190.129.208.178:96/PasarelaServices/CustomerServices?wsdl';
var wsdlOptions = {
  "overrideRootElement": {
    "namespace": "ser",
    "xmlnsAttributes": [{ "name": "xmlns:ser", "value": "http://services.vlink.com.bo/" }]
  }
};
var args = { "key": '12345', "parametros": 'parameters...' };
soap.createClient(url, wsdlOptions, function (err, client) {
  client.solicitarPago(args, function (err, result, raw, soapHeader) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

The problem was: it was necessary to establish the prefix "ser" with
[wsdlOptions](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#specifying-the-exact-namespace-definition-of-the-root-element)